# Image not showing in view on another screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

After I select an image in the photo gallery it does not show up in the view on another screen. Any ideas?? This is the prepareforsegue. I don't know if there is a problem in this part or maybe.

```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
     {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"InfoSegue"]) {
    UITabBarController* tabBar = segue.destinationViewController;

    InstructionsViewController* instructions = [tabBar.viewControllers[0]      
    viewControllers][0];
    instructions.delegate = self;

    SettingsViewController* settings = [tabBar.viewControllers[1] viewControllers][0];
    settings.delegate = self;

    MoreViewController* more = [tabBar.viewControllers[2] viewControllers][0];
    more.delegate = self;
    UINavigationController* navSubscription = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:STORYBOARD_FILE_NAME bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SubscriptionStoryboardID"];
    SubscriptionViewController* subscription = navSubscription.viewControllers[0];
    subscription.delegate = self;

    NSMutableArray* viewControllers = [tabBar.viewControllers mutableCopy];
    [viewControllers insertObject:navSubscription atIndex:viewControllers.count - 1];
    tabBar.viewControllers = viewControllers;

} else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"EditorScreenSegue"]) {
    [DesignController startDesign:_selectedDesign];

    EditorViewController* editor = segue.destinationViewController;
    editor.delegate = self;
}
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MyDesignsSegue"]) {
    MyDesignsViewController* designs = segue.destinationViewController;
    designs.delegate = self;
}
}
```

Comment: Why the drive-by downvote? You should always leave a reason unless someone already has.

Comment: I don't see any code that passes an image to the destination view controller. Debug and step through your code and show only the code where you're having a problem. Is the problem really in all three sections of prepareForSegue?

Comment: Agree, don't see where the code you've provided relates to your problem. Perhaps include snippets from the different parts of your code to illustrate the problem.

Comment: The EditorViewController is the view that I am trying to go to. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
 else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"EditorScreenSegue"]) {
    [DesignController startDesign:_selectedDesign];

    EditorViewController* editor = segue.destinationViewController;
    editor.delegate = self;

  // Use this code
  editor.selectedImage = currentImage;
  // selectedImage = its a UIImage property in EditorViewController.h
  // currentImage = its a UIImage reference for current view controller selected image object
}
```

Find the added lines here in else if block. You are not passing UIImage object then how would it get displayed. As shown in code, in next view, you should use selectedImage reference in code.

Hope this will give you a hint, what you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this has an issue.

```
- (void)openImagePickerForSource:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)source button:     
 (UIButton*)button

 {
if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:source]) {
    return;
}

UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = source;
picker.delegate = self
```

This part is the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker     
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad &&
    picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary) {
    [_popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    _popover = nil;
} else {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

// Start the Image Editor Screen
[self startedDesignWithOriginalImage:image];
}
```

and this is the EditorViewControllerDelegate.

```
- (Design *)designForEditor:(EditorViewController *)editor
{
return _selectedDesign;
}

- (UIImage *)backgroundImageForEditor:(EditorViewController *)editor
{
return _selectedBackgroundImage;
}
```